# Augmenting melanins with Prussian blue?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

Terrestrial mammals usually get their color from [melanins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanin), which makes possible a range of colors, from white to black, yellow to red, and most combinations thereof. However, [some](https://nypost.com/2021/02/22/why-dogs-are-turning-blue-and-pink-in-this-russian-city/) [dogs](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dzerzhinsk+blue+dog) appear to have gotten into some alternate pigments, possibly [Prussian blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue) (Fe<sub>7</sub>(CN)<sub>18</sub>).

Despite being related to cyanide, Prussian blue (PB) is non toxic due to the strong iron binding... and all of its constituent elements (carbon, nitrogen, iron) are generally available to mammals. From the Dzerzhinsk dogs, we can see that expressing PB as a *pigment* is clearly possible. However, could "mammals"¹ use PB as a *biochrome*? (Note that a biochrome is specifically a pigment produced *by the organism*; the real life dogs are blue because they *ingested* PB².)

(¹ If you get hung up on *Earth mammals*, you're missing the point. I'm asking about a fictional reality in which there are warm-blooded, often-furry, viviparous, lactating vertebrates. Please leave your pedantry at the door and take a check-tag.)

(² To be fair, it isn't clear that the pigment in question is *definitely* PB, or if it's some other probably-cyanide-related pigment. Feel free to either assume it *is* PB, or, if you can show that some other pigment would work and produce the same effect, feel free to answer based on that.)

Specifically, these "mammals" should:

- Produce PB via biochemical processes, and without poisoning themselves in the process.
- Be capable of producing PB *in addition* to melanin.
- Produce a *consistent* amount of PB given "typical" variations in diet. (In other words, just as most real mammals don't usually change colors dramatically due to normal variation in diet, the same should hold true for PB-based coloration.)
- Be capable of producing at least enough PB to have a normal, stable concentration of PB comparable to the Dzerzhinsk dogs.

Note 1: I don't care *why* this happened; please assume it is the result of advanced genetic engineering, or that appropriate environmental factors exist, or whatever allows you to get past that issue. You don't need to explain what that is.

Note 2: I'm aware there have been previous, more general questions about alternate biological coloration. I'm asking *specifically* about Prussian blue. I am aware there are other blue biochromes which *are* found in nature (e.g. [azulene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azulene)). For the purposes of this question, I am not interested in those. I am even less interested in blue coloration from e.g. structural coloration or other non-biochrome means.

---

**Postmortem:**

First off, thank you for some amazing answers! This got a *far* better response than I was expecting, and I am extremely thankful for that, especially to [Willk](/users/31698) and [Justin Thyme the Second](/users/61270). I wish I could accept more than one answer, but ultimately I decided on [Isaac Woods](/users/10229) [answer](/a/196934/43697) for most specifically addressing how to deal with that pesky cyanide.

Given that I explicitly stated that I don't need a naturalistic explanation, Isaac's answer seems most on point for how a sufficiently capable being might design such a process into an organism. Further, we know that mammals have access to iron, and that biological processes are capable of producing cyanide, so Isaac's answer definitely seems to pass the plausibility test.

Another note... carbon and nitrogen are readily available, but iron might be more problematic. While I did say one criteria was *consistency* of coloration, consistency is not constancy. Humans don't *usually* show a lot of color variation, but can if e.g. eating enough carrots. Moreover, we can assume that a blue critter might *desire* iron more than a non-blue critter and would thus tend to self-regulate. As noted, certain conditions, such as infections or a dietary iron deficiency, might cause changes, and that's okay. The keywords were "*normal* dietary variation" and "*dramatic* change in coloration".

Comment: Given that real-world scenarios are outlawed here, and you state this is assumed to be a result of advanced genetic engineering, or that appropriate environmental factors exist, or whatever allows you to get past that issue… don't you think you don't need to explain what you're asking for?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, this isn't a "real world scenario"; you seem to be operating from a definition thereof that would exclude any hard-science question. To your other point, there is a difference (which some folks seem to have trouble understanding) between whether an effect can be attained regardless of method used to attain it, and whether "natural causes" could lead to said effect.

Comment: When this isn't a "real world scenario", why not explain the differences you see?

If you want to augment melanins with Prussian blue, write your scenario believably. Is Frankenstein still popular after 200 years because of science, or writing?

If "hard science" doesn't kill the whole idea, why not expand your own exposition? Introduce a catalyst?

How many readers d'you think will see that there's a problem, let alone follow the details?

Your "other point" eludes me, for one, and who doubts there are differences among effect, method and "natural causes"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I am confused; you start out by saying I should give an explanation, then proceed to explain why I *shouldn't*. As for the "other point", see https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8138. As for "real world", I don't want to turn this into a multi-page debate. I fail to see how this is substantially different from other questions of similar nature, and it seems most folk are fine with it.

Comment: Good for you and still, why not write it? Why is it difficult for your critters to a PB caility naturally?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, because, so far, it wouldn't be topical in my story. ("That's a lovely shade of blue" comes up, but not wondering how it's possible any more than most stories find it necessary to explain melanins. Also, [A Wizard Did It](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt). I want my universe to *run* on (mostly) the same physics, so I want to know if PB can fit in that context, but it (Doylist) *came into existence* by Creation, or some such. (Con't...)

Comment: (Con't...) Also (from the Watsonian perspective) the people in this universe lack the uniformitarian (and unscientific) fetish to explain everything using strictly naturalistic mechanisms. They know biology and would be able to explain *how* their bodies make PB, but they *don't know* "why". And *they're okay with that*. (That's not to say they aren't *curious*, they just don't have the same *need* for a purely naturalistic explanation that some humans have.) And back in Doylist land, the explanation is that The Creator (i.e. The Author, i.e. me) just wanted them to have blue fur.

Comment: Well, how far away is your deadline that you can spend this time thus?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, a long way, I hope! Seeing as my (only) deadline is [very literal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AuthorExistenceFailure). I don't actually know if I'll ever actually publish this, and even if I do, I'm certainly not writing it as a profession. This is probably the most serious hobby project I've taken on (at least in terms of sticking to it), but I've been nibbling at it since October 2019 (just shy of 200k words, minimal editing), and, well, I'm [Nikki Spencer](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/EightMillionGods) level OCD about world-building.

Comment: Thanks for taking that much trouble and look, you yourself said "… if you get hung up on Earth mammals, you're missing the point. I'm asking about a fictional reality…" and why doesn't that apply to what you're doing? Doubly why if you've already written 200K words?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120549/discussion-between-matthew-and-robbie-goodwin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Make it in follicles

Mammals already have an answer for how you use nasty toxic stuff in biochemical reactions - how we make **thyroid hormones**. The thyroid has many follicles: small spheres of colloid (mainly a protein called thyroglobulin), surrounded by specialized cells. These cells take up iodide from the blood, and transport it into the follicle, where it is oxidised to form elemental iodine (which you don't want anywhere near anything else in your body). This iodine is then attached to residues of the thyrogobulin to form precursor thyroid hormones. See [this photo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Thyroid_hormone_synthesis.png/2560px-Thyroid_hormone_synthesis.png) for a basic illustration of the process.

In this case, I'm imagining that the skin of this animal would be made to contain follicles, expressing the right enzymes on the follicular cells to form cyanide ions by whatever process you like, but only within the follicles. By preventing it from leaving the follicle, you protect the mitochondria that would otherwise make it insanely toxic. Add free iron, and some enzymes, and you have Prussian Blue in the right place to pigment the skin.

Comment: I am awarding this because I like thinking about iodine playing the role of cyanide and I like the idea of the thyroid follicles as a no-mans land safe for dangerous chemistry.  Also if you were 14 in 2015 you have wrapped your head around biochemistry in an awesome way for a 19 year old.  Here is some rep.  Stick around!

Answer (score 9):

Although you have clarified that the creature does not have to be Earth-based, I am going to assume that it has to be Earth-type DNA-based.

For it to be a genetic trait, directly related to the process of genes, then it must be protein-based. Human genetics and DNA is all about the genetic code producing specific proteins. If the genetic DNA can not produce the necessary protein, it can not have the desired effect on the organism.

Proteins are made up of amino acids.

Amino acids are [carbon-based](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/macromolecules/proteins-and-amino-acids/a/introduction-to-proteins-and-amino-acids).

> Amino acids share a basic structure, which consists of a central
> carbon atom, also known as the alpha (α) carbon, bonded to an amino
> group

So in order to posit a DNA-mediated protein that results in a Prussia blue coloration or pigmentation, you first have to get the 'ingredients' into an amino acid, based around a carbon atom.

Since the elements in the formula for the substance creating the Prussia Blue coloration (Fe7(CN)18) are all naturally encoded in amino acids, and in fact it is already carbon-based, there does not seem to be any particular reason in genetics that what you are asking is not possible.

Although I do not know of any particular pathway to an amino acid and then a protein that would specifically result in that particular molecular structure, this part can be hand waved away. It could be possible, the details are not necessary.

Since the basic elements involved are already plentiful in the diet of a DNA-based organism, I do not see diet as an impediment.

And there does not need to be a reason for the genetic modification. It could be just a random neutral mutation that gets passed on.

**EDIT**

I am not sure if this helps, but Prussian Blue is used for [medicinal purposes](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Prussian-blue) in some human illnesses.

> Prussian blue is described as a deep blue pigment that is produced
> when the oxidation of ferrous ferrocyanide salts occurs. It contains
> ferric hexacyanoferrate(II) in a cubic lattice crystal structure. It
> is insoluble in water but also tends to form a colloid thus can exist
> in either colloidal or water-soluble form, and an insoluble form. It
> is orally administered for clinical purposes to be used as an antidote
> for certain kinds of heavy metal poisoning, such as thallium and
> radioactive isotopes of caesium. Prussian blue is included in the
> World Health Organization Model List of Essential Medicines as a
> specific antidote used in poisonings to provide symptomatic and
> supportive treatment. It was also administered in individuals exposed
> to 137-Cs+ during Goiânia accident, one of the worst radioactive
> contamination incidents that occured in Brazil, 1983.

[image: Does this look like a protein built up of amino acids?]

Also [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25465756/):

> In the development of advanced photothermal therapy (PTT), there is an
> unmet demand for constructing novel multifunctional agent for
> efficient cancer therapy in a synergic manner. In this study, a system
> based on gelatin-stabilized Prussian blue nanoparticles with
> conjugated doxorubicin (PB@Gel-DOX NPs) is proposed for combined
> photothermal therapy and enzyme-responsive drug release for tumor
> destruction.

and [this](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2020/tb/d0tb01248c#!divAbstract)

> The Prussian blue (PB) based nanostructure is a mixed-valence
> coordination network with excellent biosafety, remarkable photothermal
> effect and multiple enzyme-mimicking behaviours. Compared with other
> nanomaterials, PB-based nanoparticles (NPs) exhibit several
> unparalleled advantages in biomedical applications.

**Second Edit**

You might have a problem with [bacterial infection](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32891882/), however. The blue skin just might turn white in the presence of bacteria.

> Based on a simple sonochemical coating process, smart hospital fabrics
> with the capacity to detect live bacteria by a simple change of colour
> are presented here. Prussian Blue nanoparticles (PB-NPs) are
> sonochemically coated on polyester-cotton textiles in a single-step
> requiring 15 min. The presence of PB-NPs confers the textile with an
> intensive blue colour and with bacterial-sensing capacity. Live
> bacteria in the textile metabolize PB-NPs and reduce them to
> colourless Prussian White (PW), enabling in situ detection of
> bacterial presence in less than 6 h with the bare eye (complete colour
> change requires 40 h). The smart textile is sensitive to both
> Gram-positive and Gram-negative bacteria, responsible for most
> nosocomial infections. The redox reaction is completely reversible and
> the textile recovers its initial blue colour by re-oxidation with
> environmental oxygen, enabling its re-use. Due to its simplicity and
> versatility, the current technology can be employed in different types
> of materials for control and prevention of microbial infections in
> hospitals, industries, schools and at home.

Comment: JT2 you are the frequent WB contributor that I thought might have the biochem chops to take this on.   Can you come back to this from the standpoint of some actual biochem?

Comment: I am looking at your answer, and the depiction of the Prussian Blue molecule. That looks like a perfect model for amino acid-protein synthesis. Six cyanide amino acids composed of nitrogen and carbon, manufactured into a protein with an iron center. "Cyanides are produced by certain bacteria, fungi, and algae and are found in a number of plants." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanide No reason for cyanide to be toxic to an alien species. Whodda thought of cyanide as an amino acid? Alien biology is just weird,

Comment: It makes perfect sense.  An amino acid with the R group being cyanide.  So sensible it has to exist and after some googling I turned it up: cyanoalanine.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoalanine    There is your cyanide donor!   I think this is one of the cyanogenic compounds made by plants.  How cool.

Comment: @Willk I edited my answer to give references to medical applications in humans for Prussian Blue, so it is definitely compatible with biology.

Comment: Prussian Blue is great stuff.  Cyanide not so much but it is poison for plants too,  I think that the enzyme that makes cyanoalanine is specific to plants,  Still thinking...

Comment: @Willk The term 'toxic' covers a lot of territory. The devil is in the details. Exactly why is it toxic, and what does it do in the body that makes it toxic? Cyanide is toxic, but six cyanide molecules bound to just one iron molecule apparently is beneficial.

Comment: I gave the first 500 to Woods but I like your biochem so hang in there 24 hours for part 2.

Comment: @Willk Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Tricky, possibly to the point of notdoability**

[image: prussian blue]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue

Making Prussian Blue with biochemistry would be like juggling lit blowtorches and shurikens.  The raw materials are present in biological systems: cyanide can be produced by endogenous mammalian metabolic pathways and life needs iron.  Prussian blue can form spontaneously at sites contaminated by industrial wastes - liberated cyanide binds with iron in the soil.  So all the parts are in place.

The problem is the parts are in place in the context of delicate biological systems that will be laid waste by these parts.  Cyanide is crazy toxic and super soluble and so is handled by enzymes that bind it with sulfur.  Iron also is carefully handled with shepherding molecules because microbes want it and will take it if they can, and it will generate free radicals if given a chance.

I could imagine an enzyme which detoxified cyanide by complexing it with iron.  Prussian Blue is not very toxic and would be a good repository.  As far as I can tell, detox enzymes use sulfur or oxygen.   Iron containing enzymes keep their iron and use it to generate radicals and do chemistry.  The end products of these metabolic pathways do not contain iron.  I think sulfur must be less expensive than iron; if you can detoxify something by binding it with iron you can probably use sulfur in a similar way and save your valuable iron.

Then I was thinking: maybe dump the cyanide into a no-mans land where there is also free iron, let the prussian blue form abiogenically like it does in soil then reclaim it.  Problems: the only no-mans land available is the GI tract and it is loaded with microbes that will claim both the iron and cyanide.  Also if you can absorb Prussian Blue you can probably absorb cyanide and so the cyanide will come back and hack your biology and get bound with sulfur to detoxify it.

---

I could not dream up a mammalian biochemical path that was even a remote cousin of any actual mammalian biochemistry.  But I would like to see one.  I will put some bounty on this when I am able, to reward an answer with molecules and pathways, ideally drawn with ballpoint pen on a napkin.

Comment: "Prussian blue can form spontaneously at sites contaminated by industrial wastes - liberated cyanide binds with iron in the soil." - Ah! That might explain the dogs; the articles mention cyanide and "*used* in the production of PB", but not that the wastes are *actually* PB. But if they tend to *turn into* PB anyway, that would make sense. Also, thanks for the in-depth analysis! This is exactly the sort of answer I was hoping to get from this question.

Comment: I wouldn't say the GI tract is the only no-mans land that could be used here. What about a structure like the thyroid, with the pigment being formed in little follicles, with carefully constructed luminal membranes to avoid the finished product getting anywhere with mitochondria? If these follicles were part of the skin, they'd probably pigment it enough without release

Comment: @IsaacWoods - that is a good thought.  A purpose built no-mans land and the thyroid does do something similar with iodine.  I was looking for any biomolecule with a metal atom and so little organic decoration around it as prussian blue.   Iodothyronine is closer than anything I thought of.  Post that as an answer!

Comment: In this scenario, the enzyme would be the agent that is genetically manufactured. Interesting. Build the Prussian Blue not directly from DNA, but indirectly. See  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsami.8b10345 https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.8b05223 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxidase for a starter.

Answer (score 4):

**Protective coloration!**

It's a dog eat dog world out there.  Several closely related species of dogs have contested the top of the food chain with one another for millions of years.

In these dogs, the epithelial cells of the skin produce large quantities of nitriles.  These are produced by modifying the lysine side chains of keratin proteins in the *stratum spinosum*.  An enzyme, maybe related to [this one](https://www.nature.com/articles/nchem.1385) (I haven't accessed), has evolved to target these side chains.  Using molecular oxygen, they convert the -CH2-NH2 of lysine into -CH=NH and -C≡N, releasing two molecules of H2O.  These cells also produce an [alternative oxidase](https://academic.oup.com/femsyr/article/3/3/239/502589?login=true) for cyanide-resistant respiration.  That reduces their metabolic efficiency, but allows them to resist high HCN levels.

As the cells begin to accumulate filaggrin (which marks the beginning of the end of their metabolic function) they activate a proenzyme which then releases HCN from the side chains through a comparably targeted reduction with NADH, which they release from their mitochondria as they inactivate alternative oxidase.

Now the result would be that the dogs would reek of cyanide gas, but they don't - it would poison them.  How do they avoid this?  Ferrisomes!  These are small vesicles present abundantly in each cell, containing large amounts of transferrin secreted while the cells were still in the basal layer of the skin, which has accumulated large amounts of iron ions.  But for some time now, the pH of these vesicles has been alkaline, denaturing the protein and releasing the Fe3+ ions.  The HCN from surrounding cells enters these vesicles and is bound into ferrocyanide, which is then oxidized (maybe with molecular oxygen or NAD+) to produce ferricyanide.

The resulting epithelium therefore has outer blue layers of ferricyanide-containing vesicles.  These are pretty, and pretty harmless.  Unless and until they experience severe trauma, such as exposure to salivary amylase or stomach acid.  Then, sodium-hydrogen antiporters built into the walls of these vesicles release an abundance of stored sodium out of the vesicle, and greatly lower its pH.  This causes the ferricyanide to release HCN.  Some additional HCN may be released during digestion with stomach acid.  The resulting poisonous experience tends to dissuade members of related or unrelated species from consuming these animals.

Comment: If you can provide references to all of this, it would be excellent.

Comment: The way I wrote this I may have made it a bit unclear what is fantasy and reality.  The most interesting real antecedents I could think of are linked near the beginning. The layers of the epithelium are legit, but the "ferrisomes" are a construct you have to make (but plausibly could) and the enzymes would need to be modified with appropriate signals to localize them to those vesicles.  "Some assembly required", I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

### Be Happy, Let's not be Blue!

Prussian blue, despite the name, is actually considered by some to be a shade of grey (color being highly subjective), although various preparations make it increasingly take on a bluish hue (and given the rarity of blue, it's blue-like qualities are what are considered valuable).

It currently isn't produced biologically, so there is no biochemical pathway as of now. So if you want it, you need to handwave it into existence. But once you handwave, all your problems are solved. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with Prussian blue except it has no precedent.

**Not the answer you're looking for:** The easiest excuse is animals eating foods containing it, produced by some fictional plant that produces it (this is akin to your Dzershinsk dogs). Mammals don't tolerate cyanide intermediate compounds well, and are unlikely to develop independent production due to the toxic intermediaries. Plants use various means to make themselves resistant to cyanide, so they are your best starting point. If your animals need something but don't produce it themselves, it is really no different than a vitamin - an essential compound like vitamin C obtained from food. We obtain lots of vitamins in stable quantities from our food.

**The answer you're looking for:** There are animals that do [tolerate cyanide](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/189764/what-needs-to-be-changed-in-the-structure-of-the-human-body-in-order-not-to-die) in special ways, however, so nothing is impossible. Depending on your fictional biochemistry, it could even be toxic to some organisms and not others. For example, tomatoes are related to belladonna, and tomatine (found in tomatoes) is poisonous and/or distasteful to some insects. Given a strong selective reason for your animals to develop cyanide-based biochemistry, it is unlikely but not impossible that they produce Prussian blue initially as a byproduct, but eventually on purpose as a color. Keep in mind, however, that the blue color is only useful/serves a purpose if the organism can see blue (not a forgone conclusion) or if blue is an attractant for prey, a repellant for predators, or allows your animal to blend into their environment (and if the environment is blue, getting PB from foods is a lot more plausible).

Comment: You forgot sexual selection. When in doubt, it's a sex thing.

Comment: @No Name I didn't. I was assuming mammals that  mostly can't see blue, and who thus wouldn't select for it on that basis (we are the weirdos in mammals). But you're right in that they would be more likely to see blue if there was selective pressure to evolve blue color, so sex selection could be a thing.

Comment: A few points of contention. First, cyanide IS produced biologically in bacteria, and secondly it is not the blue color that is medically useful for humans, it is the ability of PB to attract heavy metals, and other useful properties. See my answer for references. PB is an accepted as an important drug for humans.

Comment: Carbon (India ink) is undeniably black, yet under skin it can take on a blue color.  It seems conceivable something similar could happen here.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second I'm only addressing the color part in PB. Yes, bacteria produce cyanide, but animals don't so I'm uncertain why that matters. If you're looking for metal chelators, there are lots (some easier for animals to make), and you want ones that pass out of a person (with the metals) not ones that deposit in the skin as the OP suggests. Interesting info on phototherapy BTW, it's very relevant to current efforts to make blood supplies that can safely have their self-life extended by shining (harmless) light on the blood, destroying bacterial DNA.

Comment: If bacteria produce it on earth, then it is within reason that in an alien environment they could live symbiotically inside animals, the same way mitochondria do. The OP only needs them inside the body in sufficient maintainable quantities. How they get there is irrelevant as long as it is a biological process.

Comment: Just to clarify, I never actually mentioned *skin*. I'm not *not* interested in skin, but I am *assuredly* interested in *fur* (and/or hair; same difference). In either case, though, both fur and skin eventually fall off. OTOH, my primary goal is also pigmentation, not heavy metal sequestration, though the latter is a fascinating side effect which makes me wonder if these hypothetical critters might have a "normal" level of blue tint, but turn much more blue when exposed to high levels of heavy metals, sort of like humans turning orange due to very high levels of beta carotene...